# Error after installing react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

> I have installed react native navigation following this link:
>
> https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android
>
> But I am getting errors after running **react-native run-android**
>   command.
>
> The Error is below:

```
> Task :react-native-navigation:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have tried gradlew clen command after installing react native navigation. build was successful. also tried **multiDexEnabled true**, but not working. **I am new to react native, please help me with this error.**

> My MainApplication.java file looks like this:

package com.prabhujidroid;

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

    @Override
     public boolean isDebug() {
         // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
         return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
     }

     protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
         // Add additional packages you require here
         // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
         return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
             // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
             //new VectorIconsPackage()
         );
     }

     @Override
     public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
         return getPackages();
     }

     @Override
    public String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

> build.gradle file which is inside android folder looksmlike
>   this(android/build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

> build.gradle file which is inside android/app folder looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    // compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    // buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.prabhujidroid"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

> **Package,json file goes here.**

```
    {
  "name": "rn-course",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.486"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the `package.json` file so we can see what versions of what packages you _intended_ to install. Also, include version of React Native that has been installed (if different than specified in `package.json`). Also, since most packages are constantly being updated, include the version of `react-native-navigation` you want to install. Lastly, try to install `react-native-navigation` on a new/clean RN project with newest version of `react-native` and `react-native-navigation`, the issue might already be resolved.

Comment: Ok I am trying to install it again.

Comment: Same thing happens. I am including the package.json file

Comment: Can anyone please help me about this?? I am really stucked.

Comment: You can try link library to native again by `react-native link` and compile

Answer (score 1):

Atlast I solved it. dependencies should look like this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1" <----- should be same
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1" <------ should be same
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
}
```

For me It was different